# Flutter: How to delete the Listview item onClick on icon

Tags: flutter, listviewitem

I am displaying the records on ListView using ListView.builder from api response data, i want to delete the list item when user click on icon, here is the code

```
Container(
    child:SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: FutureBuilder(
    future: _getRecord(), //getting data from this method
   builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<List<History>> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                     if(historyList.length!=0){
                      return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                        child:Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            child:Stack(
                              overflow: Overflow.visible,
                              children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                           leading:  CircleAvatar(
                             radius: 25,
                            backgroundColor:Color(int.parse(annualboxcolor))
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
                              child:Column(children: <Widget>[
                              Text(dateObj.day.toString()),  
                            ]
                            ),
                          )),
                          title: Text(snapshot.data[index].username),
                          isThreeLine: true,
                          subtitle:
                              IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.check_box,color: Colors.green,size: 30,),onPressed: (){})]) //i want to delete item on click on this icon
```

please help how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below line in onTap event of ListTile Widget.

```
 setState(() {
     snapshot.data.removeAt(index);
 });
```

Comment: It is working, thanks, but it duplicate the list item which are not delete.

Comment: i am doing the same thing for list too where i store the data, actually i am returning ```HistoryList``` on ```_getRecord``` method, so if i do this ```historyList.removeAt(index);```   before or after ```snapshot.data.removeAt(index);``` it is still duplicating the items